# Find linq Entity through a string value

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

How can I receive a string value, for example, "User" and find a Entity with this name, and use this Entity as a type?

Thanks!!

**EDITED**: "User" is the name of the Entity in dbml, not a property

Comment: Is User the type of the entity or the value of one of the entity's properties?  More information would help.

Comment: Hi tvanfosson - "User" is my Entity in dbml

Answer (score 2):

you could possibly use the Mapping.GetTables() on your datacontext, ie:

```
var tables = context.Mapping.GetTables().ToList();
```

then search through that to find the name.